# javascript phone validataion

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
//include the DB connection
include("includes/config.php");
//include the header
include("includes/header.php");
?>
<?php
//checks if the form was submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //get form values when submitted
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . time() . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
    {

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `login`(`name`,`email`,`phone`,`password`,`file`,`subject`)VALUES('$name','$email','$phone','$password',
            '$target_file','$subject')");

        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } 
    else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>

<div class="form">
<form action="" method="post" name="registration" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
    <table width="500" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input name="name" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" value="<?php //echo $userName ;?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input name="email" type="email" class="input" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email ID "value=" <?php //echo $userEmail ;?>"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Phone</td>
        <td><input name="phone" type="text"  class="input" placeholder="Please Enter Your Phone  Number" value="<?php //echo $userPhone;?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input name="password" type="password" class="input" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Upload file</td>
        <td><input name="file" type="file" class="input" value="" </td>



      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>Subject</td>

        <td><textarea name="subject" cols="" rows="" class="input" placeholder="Please Enter Your Query "/> <?php //echo $userSubject;?></textarea></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      </tr>


        </table>
</form>     
</div>

<?php
//include the footer
include("includes/footer.php");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function formValidation()  
{   
    var uname = document.registration.name; 
    var uphone= document.registration.phone;
    if(allLetter(uname))  
    {
        if(phonenumber(uphone))  
        {
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function allLetter(uname)  
{   

    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
    if(uname.value.match(letters))  
    {  

        return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');  
        uname.focus();  
        return false;  
    }  
} 

function phonenumber(inputtxt)  
{  
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
    if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))  
    {  
      return true;  
    }  
   else
    {  
        alert("message");  
        return false;  
    }  
}  
</script>
```

for the user name the code for validation works but for the phone validation it's not working,i want phone validation for empty field check and format check and email check.help me out as i'm new to javascript

Comment: Where is your validation code

Comment: what value(s) fails for phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function formValidation()
    {
    var phone=document.forms["registration"]["phone"].value;
    var phone_num = /^\d{10}$/;  
        if (phone=="")
        {
            alert("enter your phone number");
            return false;
        }
        else if(phone) 
        {
            if(!phone_num.test(phone)) 
        {  
         alert("Not a valid Phone Number");  
         return false;
        }
        }
        var email = document.forms["registration"]["email"].value;
        if (email=="")
            {
                alert("enter your email id");
                return false;
            }
        var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length)
        {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define your changes, let OP know what you have changed and why he should using your script

Comment: @hanan now my code for usename validation doesn't works

Comment: This is simple javaScript validation.. let me know what your error upto?

Answer (score 0):

you have a `typo` in your phone function an extra `(`:

try:

`if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))`

instead of `if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))`

`PS:` Tip do look and use console tools while working with `JS`